# Count repeating "objects" in a picture

Tags: cnn, object-detection, image-recognition, faster-rcnn

This is my first data-science project and I would love to get some guidance to know how to get started.

My problem is the following:
I want to count objects that are in a picture. This picture has a special characteristic, it's going to be "objects" over a white background.

For example:

- seeds
- coffee beans
- painted black dots
- etc.

The input for example would be:

[image]

The output:
Objects: 9

[image]

I've been doing some research already and I found many places that they recommend the use of an R-CNN to locate and classify my "items" in the picture.

This sounds like a good idea but the problem I see here is that I do not know what I'm going to have in the picture. I know there are going to be "repeated items" of the same type and class but it could be anything.

As I don't know what I'm going to have in the picture I don't know what to use to train my model.

How should I proceed?

Comment: If the background is always white (or something distinctly different than the color of the objects) you could probably get far using normal computer vision techniques.

Comment: as Oxbowerce mentions computer vision methods like blob detection would be great

Answer (score 1):

If you really do need to use a ML solution for this problem (as opposed to a strict computer vision solution), most (all?) frameworks will return a list of detections after running inference.

I'll use Tensorflow and this [object detection tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_object_detection) as an example.
If you run the colab and select the text cell with the headline "Visualizing the results" and run all the cells above, it will have downloaded a model and run inference on a picture when it's done.

Insert a code cell and add `print(result["detection_classes"])` and run it. That should give output along the lines of:

```py
[[38.  1.  1. 38. 38. 38.  1.  1. 38.  1.  1. 38.  1.  1.  1. 38. 42. 42.
 1. 38. 42. 38.  1.  1.  1. 31. 38. 38. 42.  1. 31. 27.  1.  1. 38.  1.
 2. 38.  1. 38. 37. 38. 38. 27. 38. 38. 38. 44. 38. 38. 27.  1.  1. 38.
 3.  1. 38. 42. 16. 38.  9.  1.  1. 27. 27. 38. 38.  1. 38. 38.  1.  1.
 4. 38. 31. 38.  1. 38. 38. 31. 42.  9. 38. 34. 40. 38. 38.  1. 38. 38.
 5.  3. 18. 27. 38. 18.  1. 31. 42. 38.]]
```

Each of the numbers in the list maps to one of the classes. In this case you will find the classes in the variable `category_index`.

Now you can use your favorite python method to count the occurrences. A simple implementation could look something like this:

```py
def count_classes(detections: list) -> tuple:
  ret_tuple = {}
  for detection in detections:
    if detection in ret_tuple.keys():
      ret_tuple[detection] += 1
    else:
      ret_tuple[detection] = 1
  return ret_tuple
```

Running the above in the colab will give the following:

```py
count_classes(result["detection_classes"][0])
...
{1.0: 30,
 3.0: 1,
 9.0: 2,
 16.0: 1,
 18.0: 3,
 27.0: 6,
 31.0: 5,
 34.0: 1,
 37.0: 1,
 38.0: 41,
 40.0: 1,
 42.0: 7,
 44.0: 1}
```